# Why does this suggested edit's character count not agree with the diff?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, diff

[This suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/80309) has “added 3408 characters in body”, yet the diff only shows 11 added characters. Why?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hmm, I just tried to inspect this, and then I discovered that there's no way to view the source (raw markdown syntax) for suggested edits. That *used* to be there, and I'd very much like it back!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a <2k user across the network, I think I can shed some light here. When a user goes to re-edit a post on which he has a pending suggested edit, the software automatically fills in the edit summary from the most recent version of the suggested edit. So assuming that the behavior hasn't changed since 2011, a likely explanation is that the user in question *did* initially propose an edit at 10:04 that added some 3000+ characters, and then, over the subsequent 2-hour period before rejection, modified the suggestion at least once until it became the one-line change we see preserved in the linked review. If the user never bothered to touch the edit summary box throughout the whole process, the automatically-generated summary from the initial proposal would remain – completely untouched – on all subsequent versions of the suggestion despite no longer being an accurate reflection of the content.

Comment: True, that's the most likely explanation, and only a dev can confirm for sure.

Answer (score 4):

There are just two cases when this would happen

1. [image]
2. bug

It's probably that first case, but I have no idea why would OP do it

Comment: Ah, perhaps some artifact left over from a [previous rejected edit by the same user](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/80097) (which is only about 2000 characters long though)?

Comment: @Gilles: probablyy

Answer (score 2):

Just come across [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13938567/revisions) where there have been nowhere near 16,261 characters added.

This suggest that it's a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) as the chances of the OP, who's only interacted with one question, getting the grammar correct for the automatically created edit description is minimal.

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Could very well be simply a huge amount of whitespace added.</strike>

They don't show up in the diff, but the characters are counted towards that number.

(Random edit to a sandbox post [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/93997/revisions) - shows 186 chars added to body that are not visible in the diff.)

*This theory has been debunked*: [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRJAe.png) and [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UH4Sv.png) show that whitespace does show up in the suggested edit diff view. (Thanks Gilles for the captures!)

Comment: Shouldn't the whitespace be indicated (with →) in the markdown diff? Or does that happen only for whitespace at the beginning of a line? If it isn't, I might turn this into a feature request.

Comment: Not sure... I just made a test edit on your question, but... I can't see the suggested edits on meta :-) ...

Comment: Thanks for the experiment, [here's a screenshot of the markdown diff view of your edit](http://i.imgur.com/UPIJz.png). How much whitespace did you add at the end of the line?

Comment: Well, there goes my theory... I add three spaces on the first line then 10 or so empty lines that are clearly visible in that screenshot. I'll delete this shortly.

Comment: Don't delete this yet. Can you try adding lots of space characters at the end of the line? (I'd do it, but I can't suggest edits on Meta, and I don't want to disrupt another site.)

Comment: Ok: I just tried adding 100 spaces at the end of the first line, and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks. [There goes that theory](http://i.imgur.com/OBxfF.png): the spaces do show up as →.